Equivalent definition of Lebesgue outer measure as product measure
Let us assume the usual definition of $n$-dimensional Lebesgue outer measure:
$$\lambda^*_n(E):=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty v(Q_i)\colon E\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} Q_i, Q_i -\text{ products of intervals }\right\},$$
where $v(Q)$ is the volume of $Q$. I want to show that
$$\lambda_{n+m}^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_n(A_i)\cdot \lambda_m(B_i)\colon E\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} (A_i\times B_i), A_i \in \mathcal L_n \text{ and } B_i\in \mathcal L_m\right\},$$
where $\mathcal L_n$ is the sigma-field of Lebesgue measurable sets. This equality basically says that $(n+m)$-dimensional Lebesgue measure is the product measure.
I concluded such information the book 'Measure theory and fine properties of functions' (by Evans and Gariepy), because the Lebesgue measure is defined in a way different than usual there (so correct me if the equality does not hold).
As for the proof, one inequality is obvious because products of intervals are Lebesgue measurable and the measure is equal to the volume. However, I don't know the proof for the other one.
